# Why I am I getting only azure active direcoty authintication is enabled when trying to connect azure aql server?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have created azure sql server machine in azure portal.

While creating the machine I for got to add sql server authintication.

So Now When I try to login,Only azure active direcoty authintication is enabled.

How Can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sloved it by az sql server ad-only-auth disable --resource-group mygroup --name myServer

Comment: Good to see you have solved your issue. You can [accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) that will help others who meet a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and Got expected results as below:

- Firstly, I have created a SQL server with Ad authentication.
- Then Opened SQL Server in Portal
- Then click on settings Section
- Then click on Azure Active directory and then unselect Azure active directory authentication only and then save it as below:

[image]

Then Click on Overview of SQL Server and Click on Reset password as below:

[image]

Now set a password as below:

[image]

Now tested in Sql database as below and it worked :

[image]

Try to follow above process to change the authentication mode as mine got changed.